# Django default LoginTest failing

Tags: django, django-testing

When I run my project's default tests, one test is failing:

FAIL: test_current_site_in_context_after_login (django.contrib.auth.tests.views.LoginTest)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Dropbox/dotfiles/.virtualenvs/mysite/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/tests/views.py", line 294, in test_current_site_in_context_after_login
    self.assertEqual(response.context['site_name'], site.name)
AssertionError: 'MySite' != u'example.com'

My settings.py file contains:

```
SITE_NAME = 'MySite'
```

I load the SITE_NAME in my context at the end of the settings file with:

```
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = GLOBAL_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'utils.context_processors.mysite',
)
```

utils/context_processors.py contains:

```
from mysite import settings
def mysite(request):
    return {
        'site_name': settings.SITE_NAME,
        'request': request
    }
```

I've looked at the source code but I don't understand why the test is comparing my site's name to 'example.com'.  I've also looked at the django.contrib.sites.models.Site class and am wondering if I need to clear the Site object cache.  However, I don't have a CACHES setting.  Could there be some conflict in a .pyc file such that I need to delete all the pyc files in my virtualenv?

BTW, I'm running Django 1.4.2 and 2.7.1.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you hardcode the SITE_NAME in your settings. You should use `Site.objects.get_current()` in your middleware/view instead: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/sites/#hooking-into-the-current-site-from-views

Comment: I read the docs you referred to and made the change and now I'm getting the error, "django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the Django "sites framework" without having set the SITE_ID setting..."  But Django created the setting 
"SITE_ID = 1" in my settings file and I have it before the SITE_NAME setting which I just changed.  This error smells funny...

Comment: Sorry, maybe my explanation was a bit confusing. Site objects are meant to be dynamic. That means you maybe should get rid of your SITE_NAME setting completely and refer to the site database object instead. You could put the get_current()-method in your middleware or your view directly. Another option would be to not use the sites-framework at all (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/#requestsite-objects).

Comment: I had to delete not only SITE_NAME but also the TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS directive in order to stop the error from occurring.  I still don't understand what the problem was but I need to move on. I'll give you credit because you at least took the time to help me out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I recently ran into this problem and I fixed it by add the following to my settings.py file:

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

From the Django documentation at [Django Settings Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/?from=olddocs#site-id):

> SITE_ID
>
> Default: Not defined
>
> The ID, as an integer, of the current site in the django_site database table. This is used so that application data can hook into specific sites and a single database can manage content for multiple sites.